# WMIC is running every second... how can I stop running it?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, wmic

when I enter a server using Remote Desktop connection, I notice that every second a console window is opened and closed immediately.

I could take a screenshot so I could see that the program that is run every second is "WMIC".

[image]

I have looked at scheduled tasks and it is not there. Why is it running? how can I stop this behaviour?

Thanks

Jaime

Comment: You should use procmon : https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon start a capture, wait for the next 'flash', stop the capture, press CTRL-T to show the process tree and find the wmic instance. You'll be able to find the parent process and the command line.